# Unusual characters in Brace expansion of characters in bash

Tags: bash

I was generating random characters for some purpose. By mistake I try the following in a terminal and got some surprising result. I am using `bash` shell provided by Ubuntu.

```
$ echo {Z..a}
Z [  ] ^ _ ` a
```

Inspiring by this result, I did

```
$ echo {z..A}
z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a ` _ ^ ]  [ Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A
```

My question is what are these five characters `` [  ] ^ _ ` `` doing in the range. Do they have any special meaning or I am just performing some forbidden action.

<sup>People usually use `$ echo {{A..Z},{a..z}}` in order to get both lower as well as the upper case characters,</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at ascii table. After uppercase Z there are exactly those characters that you got, so there's no surprise - bash read ascii table from where you told it to, to where you told it to. `\` does not show up, though, because it is usually used for escape sequences like `\n` - a newline

[image]

Comment: You have aptly pointed it out. I missed that point. One little addition \ appeared as an extra space. Thanks +1.

Comment: If you want a quick look at the ASCII table, do `man ascii`.